# ASP.NET 2.0 Asynchronous User Control Not Working

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, asynchronous

I'm trying to get a user control working asynchronously, yet no matter what I do it continues to work synchronously. I've stripped it down to its bare minimum as a test web application. This would be the user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    SqlConnection m_oConnection;
    SqlCommand    m_oCommand;

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.Warn("Page_Load");
        string strDSN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSN"].ConnectionString + ";async=true";
        string strSQL = "waitfor delay '00:00:10'; select * from MyTable";

        m_oConnection = new SqlConnection(strDSN);
        m_oCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, m_oConnection);
        m_oConnection.Open();

        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(new BeginEventHandler(BeginHandler), new EndEventHandler(EndHandler), new EndEventHandler(TimeoutHandler), null, true));
        Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks();
    }

    IAsyncResult BeginHandler(object src, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        Trace.Warn("BeginHandler");
        return m_oCommand.BeginExecuteReader(cb, state);
    }

    void EndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Trace.Warn("EndHandler");
        GridView1.DataSource = m_oCommand.EndExecuteReader(ar);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        m_oConnection.Close();
    }

    void TimeoutHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Trace.Warn("TimeoutHandler");
    }
</script>
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" />
```

And this would be the page in which I host the control three times:

```
<%@ page language="C#" trace="true" async="true" asynctimeout="60" %>
<%@ register tagprefix="uc" tagname="mycontrol" src="~/MyControl.ascx" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl1" runat="server" />
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl2" runat="server" />
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl3" runat="server" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The page gets displayed without errors, but the trace at the bottom of the page shows each control instance is processed synchronously. What am I doing wrong? Is there a configuration setting somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like I can answer my own question. The user control should not be calling `Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks`. By doing that, the control was adding the async task, running it, and waiting for it to complete.

Instead, each instance of the user control should call only `Page.RegisterAsyncTask`. After each control instance has done this the page automatically calls `RegistereAsyncTask` running all three registered async tasks simultaniously.

So here is the new user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
    SqlConnection m_oConnection;
    SqlCommand    m_oCommand;

    void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Trace.Warn(ID, "Page_Load - " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());
        string strDSN = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DSN"].ConnectionString + ";async=true";
        string strSQL = "waitfor delay '00:00:10'; select * from TEProcessedPerDay where Date > dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate()) order by Date asc";

        m_oConnection = new SqlConnection(strDSN);
        m_oCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, m_oConnection);
        m_oConnection.Open();

        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(new BeginEventHandler(BeginHandler), new EndEventHandler(EndHandler), new EndEventHandler(TimeoutHandler), null, true));
    }

    IAsyncResult BeginHandler(object src, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        Trace.Warn(ID, "BeginHandler - " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());
        return m_oCommand.BeginExecuteReader(cb, state);
    }

    void EndHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Trace.Warn(ID, "EndHandler - " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());
        GridView1.DataSource = m_oCommand.EndExecuteReader(ar);
        GridView1.DataBind();
        m_oConnection.Close();
    }

    void TimeoutHandler(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Trace.Warn(ID, "TimeoutHandler - " + Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode().ToString());
    }
</script>
<asp:gridview id="GridView1" runat="server" />
```

And the unchanged page that creates three instances of the control:

```
<%@ page language="C#" async="true" trace="true" %>
<%@ register tagprefix="uc" tagname="mycontrol" src="~/MyControl.ascx" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl1" runat="server" />
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl2" runat="server" />
            <uc:mycontrol id="MyControl3" runat="server" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mate.. mine still not working even though not using "ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks". The page still waiting the user control to complete.. any ideas?

Comment: So what if you want to execute something asynchronously AFTER the page has been rendered?  For example, a Search page... you only want to update the Search Results UpdatePanel [Ajax] from a potentially long running query.

Comment: I'm trying to do this same thing, but like user384080, I'm finding that my code, as well as the code above, runs synchronously.  I just the same code, but just changed the call to the database with a sleep of 2 seconds.  The page will take 2n seconds to load where n=the number of instances of the control, and if you look at the trace they are all running in serial.

Comment: EDIT: never mind I'm an idiot.  I thought I had commented out the ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks line but I didn't.  Works now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I may add a little to the above post, we should not call the `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTassk` explicitly unless there is a compelling reason. once you register the async task, the ASP.NET framework will execute all these tasks right after the `OnPrerender` event of the page lifecycle.

An example for the usage of `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks` could be;
Sometimes you may need to ensure that several async operations are completed before calling another async task. in a situation like this it is justifiable to use `ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks`.