# Async User Control load in Page_Load event

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, user-controls

I have a page that consist of 4 user control that each one load in a tab. one of this user controls show bing map based on our data to users.
The problem is that the Page_Load of our page is dependent to internet connection of users.
How can we load this user control asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clear from your post the nature of the long running task that you think can benefit from changing it to asynchronous, I think you'll find good clues to "asynchronous UserControls" in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273546/asp-net-2-0-asynchronous-user-control-not-working)

Also, the article [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45) is an "official" tutorial that shows how to spin asynchronous processing at a more granular level.

I am curious to see some code for my own selfish learning goals, if you can share.

Answer (score -1):

Could you clarify how Page_Load is dependent on Internet Connection?

Please check following link, which shows how to load user control asynchronously:

[Load User Control Asynchronously](http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/)